# Bulk Inserting Into Multiple Tables With Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a custom field modeling system that can be attached to multiple types of records by use of a join table. The fields themselves know nothing about the records they are attached to.

```
custom_fields
-------------
int: id
name: varchar(50)
type: int

field_values
------------
int: id
value: varchar(255)
```

To attach a field to a blog post I would create the following join tables

```
blog_post_fields
----------
id: int
custom_field_id: int

blog_post_field_values
----------------------
id: int
blog_post_id: int
blog_post_field: int
```

This is working fine so far and allows for model fields like tags where the field could be attached to multiple entities with the same pool of values.

Where I'm running into an issue is bulk inserting. Say I want to create a new field called `expires` and update all my existing blog posts to have a value of `never`. Given the above schema how could I insert a `blog_post_value` and a corresponding `field_value` for all of my blog posts?

Comment: If you're inserting a value whenever there's a new field, how is this different from adding a new column to the table? If `never` is the default, maybe you should handle it somewhere besides in the data. What happens if someone wants `never` but then the default changes?

Comment: I can't quite get across your data model, but to do what you want you just `INSERT INTO linkTable SELECT blogid FROM ExistingBlogTable`